# Type problem with CodeGenFunction/CodeGenModule with LLVM/Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, llvm, monads

I am, for some time, experimenting with [LLVM](http://llvm.org), simply because. It does, however, consume more of my time than I thought.

I dabbled with the C++ bindings, but I left C++ years ago for obvious reasons. I tried the OCaml bindings, but I disliked OCaml mostly for the cumbersome build system, among other problems.

So I got stuck with the [LLVM module for Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-0.9.1.0), which is nicely type safe and feels very Haskell. But documentation lacks somewhat, as the only examples are the ones in some [Blog](http://augustss.blogspot.com/search/label/LLVM).

To cut it short, I have been starting doing a simple compiler for [PL/0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/0). And I have, after just two days of dedication, worked out as far as this (the parser was no problem, Parsec is my chum):

AST module

```
module AST where

data Statement
    = Assign String Expression
    | Call String
    | Write String
    | If Condition Statement
    | While Condition Statement
    | Begin [Statement]
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Condition
    = Odd Expression
    | Eq Expression Expression
    | Ne Expression Expression
    | Gt Expression Expression
    | Lt Expression Expression
    | Ge Expression Expression
    | Le Expression Expression
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Expression
    = Identifier String
    | Number Integer
    | Plus Expression Expression
    | Minus Expression Expression
    | Multiply Expression Expression
    | Divide Expression Expression
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Block = Block {
        blockConsts :: [(String, Integer)],
        blockVars :: [String],
        blockProcs :: [Procedure],
        blockStatement :: Statement
    }
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Procedure = Procedure String Block
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Codegen module:

```
module Codegen {-(writeModule)-} where

import LLVM.Core
import AST
import Data.Int (Int64)
import Data.Word (Word8, Word32)

codegenExpr :: [(String, Value (Ptr Int64))] -> Expression -> CodeGenFunction r (Value Int64)
codegenExpr ls (Identifier s) = case lookup s ls of
    Nothing -> error $ "unknown identifier: " ++ s
    (Just v) -> load v
codegenExpr _ (Number n) = return $ valueOf $ fromIntegral n
codegenExpr ls (Plus e1 e2)     = arith ls e1 e2 iadd
codegenExpr ls (Minus e1 e2)    = arith ls e1 e2 isub
codegenExpr ls (Multiply e1 e2) = arith ls e1 e2 imul
codegenExpr ls (Divide e1 e2)   = arith ls e1 e2 idiv

arith ls e1 e2 f = do
    lhs <- codegenExpr ls e1
    rhs <- codegenExpr ls e2
    f lhs rhs

codegenCond :: [(String, Value (Ptr Int64))] -> Condition -> CodeGenFunction r (Value Bool)
codegenCond ls (Eq e1 e2) = cnd ls e1 e2 CmpEQ
codegenCond ls (Ne e1 e2) = cnd ls e1 e2 CmpNE
codegenCond ls (Gt e1 e2) = cnd ls e1 e2 CmpGT
codegenCond ls (Lt e1 e2) = cnd ls e1 e2 CmpLT
codegenCond ls (Ge e1 e2) = cnd ls e1 e2 CmpGE
codegenCond ls (Le e1 e2) = cnd ls e1 e2 CmpLE

cnd ls e1 e2 f = do
    lhs <- codegenExpr ls e1
    rhs <- codegenExpr ls e2
    cmp f lhs rhs

codegenStatement :: [(String, Value (Ptr Int64))] -> Statement -> CodeGenFunction () ()
codegenStatement ls (Assign id e) = case lookup id ls of
    Nothing -> error $ "unknown identifier: " ++ id
    (Just v) -> do
        val <- codegenExpr ls e
        store val v
codegenStatement ls (Begin stmts) = mapM_ (codegenStatement ls) stmts
codegenStatement ls (If cond s1) = do
    ifbl <- newBasicBlock
    thenbl <- newBasicBlock

    cnd <- codegenCond ls cond
    condBr cnd ifbl thenbl

    defineBasicBlock ifbl
    codegenStatement ls s1
    ret ()

    defineBasicBlock thenbl
    ret ()
codegenStatement ls (While cond s) = do
    exit <- newBasicBlock
    while <- newBasicBlock

    defineBasicBlock while
    cnd <- codegenCond ls cond
    codegenStatement ls s
    condBr cnd while exit

    defineBasicBlock exit
    ret ()

codegenBlock :: [(String, Value (Ptr Int64))] -> Block -> CodeGenModule (Function ())
codegenBlock vls (Block _ vars _ stmt) = do
    -- And here is the type error
    func <- createFunction ExternalLinkage $ do
        ls <- mapM named vars
        codegenStatement (vls ++ ls) stmt
        mapM_ (free . snd) ls
    return func
    where
        named n = do
            v <- alloca
            return (n, v)

writeModule bl file = do
    m <- newModule
    defineModule m $ codegenBlock [] bl
    writeBitcodeToFile file m
```

So yeah, lots of code, but complete. The type error I get is this:

```
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
[1 of 2] Compiling AST              ( AST.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling Codegen          ( Codegen.hs, interpreted )

Codegen.hs:71:13:
    No instances for (IsFunction (),
                      FunctionArgs () (CodeGenFunction () ()) (CodeGenFunction r0 ()))
      arising from a use of `createFunction'
    Possible fix:
      add instance declarations for
      (IsFunction (),
       FunctionArgs () (CodeGenFunction () ()) (CodeGenFunction r0 ()))
    In the expression: createFunction ExternalLinkage
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        func <- createFunction ExternalLinkage
              $ do { ls <- mapM named vars;
                     codegenStatement (vls ++ ls) stmt;
                     mapM_ (free . snd) ls }
    In the expression:
      do { func <- createFunction ExternalLinkage
                 $ do { ls <- mapM named vars;
                        codegenStatement (vls ++ ls) stmt;
                        .... };

       return func }
```

As I said, I've take most of the examples from the mentioned Block, and there it was written like that. I've somehow no idea how to fix this.

As always, I spend more time satisfying the type checker than doing new code.

Comment: What is the line, the error message points to?

Comment: @FUZxxl I put a comment to the line, it is just in the `codegenBlock` function, line 79 in my file.

Comment: A few words about the LLVM module.  For some reason Haddock leaves out a lot of functions, so you really need to look at the source to know about everything (vectors, for example).  Also, the synthesizer-llvm package (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Synthesizer) is probably the biggest LLVM example which is available on hackage, so you might want to look there as well.

Comment: @Lohn L: Thanks for the tip, I leaved through the source, but I missed the functions for getting a function out of a module. Does it mean I have to carry the `Function` values around myself if I want to call them in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with LLVM, so I don't know if it makes any sense, but changing the type signature of `codegenBlock` from

```
[(String, Value (Ptr Int64))] -> Block -> CodeGenModule (Function ())
```

to

```
[(String, Value (Ptr Int64))] -> Block -> CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
```

satisifies the type checker, since there is no instance `IsFunction ()`, but there is one for `IsFunction (IO a)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot that LLVM is C-based, so any function is kind of impure.

Answer (score 3):

As hammar says, your IsFunction call isn't at the right type. `IsFunction` is defined for:

```
class IsType a => IsFunction a where
  llvm-0.9.1.0:LLVM.Core.Type.funcType :: [TypeDesc] -> a -> TypeDesc
    -- Defined in llvm-0.9.1.0:LLVM.Core.Type

instance [incoherent] IsFirstClass a => IsFunction (VarArgs a)
  -- Defined in llvm-0.9.1.0:LLVM.Core.Type

instance [incoherent] IsFirstClass a => IsFunction (IO a)
  -- Defined in llvm-0.9.1.0:LLVM.Core.Type

instance [incoherent] (IsFirstClass a, IsFunction b) =>
                      IsFunction (a -> b)
```

that is, for VarArgs, for IO and for function types. Not for `()` types. So I suspect you mean to use `IO ()` in the type:

```
codegenBlock :: [(String, Value (Ptr Int64))] -> Block -> CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
```

?